# C++ Accessing define macros data

Tags: c++

I have a C++ header file that has a definition like this...

`#define TEMP {0x04,0x06,0xAA,0xBF ...}`

How do I access that data in my C++ program?

For example? Let's say I wanted to capture the single byte?

How can I assign a variable of type `uint8_t` named `x` to the third byte in the TEMP structure?

`uint8_t x = TEMP[2];` ?

Comment: Did you code that? What error did you get?

Comment: That is no data. Just text. Not clear what your problem is, please clarify!

Answer (score 3):

Macro is simply pasted in source code on compilation.

So, you can do something like this:

```
char tmp[] = TEMP; // which expands to 'char tmp[] = {0x04, 0x06, ...}'
```

and then you work with it, like with usual array.

Answer (score 1):

keep an array like this

```
uint8_t temp[] = TEMP;
```

which will expand to

```
uint8_t temp = {0x04,0x06,0xAA,0xBF};
```

then you can access the third value like this

```
uint8_t x = temp[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

`uint8_t x = std::vector<uint8_t>(TEMP)[2];` works but inelegantly.